SLAM TOOLBOX: Moving Interactive markers chrashes the node
I am using the SLAM toolbox with O. I serialized a map that contains a big area; the map is about 7391 x 14586 mapped with a resolution of about 0.05. This size is because I started the mapping process with an arbitrary start map position (x,y,heading), but there are less than 50 interactive markers.
When I try to open the pose_graph offline and move an interactive marker, the system kills the node. I can't even select one interactive marker; a click crashes the node. But if the node is near the map frame_id, the node does not crash, and the map is moved as expected.
This is the log:
Callback][346]: SlamToolbox: Toggling on interactive mode.
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-1]   what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)

Is there a parameter that conditions the distance from the map frame to the interactive marker to exit the node?
Those are my slam parameters; I increased a lot stack_size_to_use:
slam_toolbox:
ros__parameters:
# Plugin params
solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
ceres_loss_function: None

# ROS Parameters
odom_frame: odom
map_frame: map
base_frame: base_link
scan_topic: /scan
use_map_saver: true
mode: mapping #localization

# if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
# or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
# will use pose

map_file_name: /workspace/pose_graph_full
map_start_pose: [350.0, 650.0, 0.0]
# map_start_at_dock: true



debug_logging: false
throttle_scans: 1
transform_publish_period: 0.2 #if 0 never publishes odometry
map_update_interval: 5.0
resolution: 0.05
max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
minimum_time_interval: 0.5
transform_timeout: 0.2
tf_buffer_duration: 30.
stack_size_to_use: 800000000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize large maps
enable_interactive_mode: true

# General Parameters
use_scan_matching: true
use_scan_barycenter: true
minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
scan_buffer_size: 100
scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
do_loop_closing: true 
loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

# Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

# Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

# Scan Matcher Parameters
distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
use_response_expansion: true

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide me.
